# Anyone know how to hold a 74ls93?

Tags: flipflop, counter

I need to have a system where the [74ls93](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fsn74ls93) holds and does not change until they are cleared. Does anyone know of a relatively simple way to do this?
Edit: Nevermind all, figured out how to do it by introducing an AND gate after the clock.

Comment: 1) show us the schematic 2) what does the datasheet tell you about clearing the counter?

Comment: Yes, I know how to hold a 73ls93 :)

Comment: The only way would be to gate the clock (with an AND gate) but clock gating is reguarded as a bad idea as it can cause glitches.  There are better counter deviecs that have an enable input.

Comment: I don't get what do you mean with 'hold', sorry. You mean it doesn't count?

Comment: If you've solved your problem then you should post the solution as an answer instead of editing your question with it.

Answer (score 2):

Gate the clock is the only way with a ripple counter like the ‘ls93. Maybe choose a different, synchronous counter that has a clock enable, like the [CD4016](http://grobotronics.com/images/datasheets/cd4016.pdf).